# pointer to pointer inaccuracies

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I was working with 2D arrays, and tried passing it from one function to another. I've seen all the answers in here regarding that, and none of them seem to answer this particular type of problem. Its a simple thing I'm trying to achieve, but the answer is weird.

Here's the main():

```
int main(void)
{   
 int i=0,j=0,n=0,n2=0;    
 double **a, **a1, b=0; 

 printf("Enter 'n2' :");
 scanf("%d", &n2);


 a= makearray(n2);
 for(i=0; i < n2; i++){
     for(j=0; j < n2; j++){         
         a[i][j] = j;
         printf("%.f ",a[i][j]);
    }
     printf("\n");
  }

 printf("\n\n\n");

 for(i=0; i < n2; i++){ // print a
      for(j=0; j < n2; j++){
         b = a[i][j];
         printf("%.f ", b);
     }
     printf("\n");
 }

 printf("\n\n\n");
 return 0;
}
```

The function *makearray()* just returns a pointer to a pointer for the 2D array of size passed as an argument.

makearray() is:

```
double** makearray(int n2)
{
int i=0;
double** a;

a = malloc(n2 * sizeof(int *));
if(a == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    exit(0);
    }

for(i = 0; i < n2; i++){
    a[i] = malloc(n2 * sizeof(int));
    if(a[i] == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit(0);
        }
    }

return a;

}
```

You can input 'n2', where (n2 x n2) becomes the matrix size , and with n=9, the output is:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 

0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2
0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2
0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2
0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2
0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2
0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2
0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2
0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

I've not modified the first array in any way, just printed it again, any ideas why those two are different?

Comment: when you `exit(0)` you don't `free` the array, probably the OS will, but i don't think it's good practice to do that.

Comment: `sizeof(int *)` , `sizeof(int)` at `makearray` : `int` --> `double`

Comment: I noticed that you don't ever call `free`, you should. And also, when you have this kind of issue you should use a debugger, it will save you a lot of problems.

Comment: Any suggestions on the type of debugger to use?

Comment: And ive changed the code to free the memory now. cheers for pointing that out.

Comment: It depends on the OS you are using, but for me on Linux, [valgrind (a memory debugger)](http://www.valgrind.org) immediatelly helped me find the problem, without even looking at the code.

Comment: will look into that, cheers for the quick reply... made my day!

Comment: the code should check the returned value from the scanf function to assure successful input/conversion.

Comment: the data being manipulated is double so this line: 'a = malloc(n2 * sizeof(int *));' should be: 'a = malloc(n2 * sizeof(double *));'  it 'might' not make a difference, depending on the implementation of 'double' and 'int'.

Comment: the data being manipulated is double so this line: 'a[i] = malloc(n2 * sizeof(int));' should be: 'a[i] = malloc(n2 * sizeof(double));' it 'might' not make a difference, depending on the implementation of 'double' and 'int'.

Comment: this line: 'double **a, **a1, b=0;' is initializing the double variable 'b' with an integer.  the line should be: 'double **a, **a1, b=0.0;'

Comment: you say you modified the code to call free() for each of the malloc'd memory areas, but I'm not seeing that change in the code!  Please update the question by adding an edit area showing the modified code

Comment: for these lines: 'printf("%.f ",a[i][j]);' the format string is expecting a float, but the actual value is a double.  suggest using: printf("%1.0lf ",a[i][j]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your makearray, the `malloc` is using `sizeof(int)`, but you're creating an array for `double`s. Ints typically use `4 bytes`, but `double`s use `8 bytes`. So you aren't `malloc`-ing enough memory for a 2-d array of doubles.

Comment: besides me looking incredibly inept at this, did the above(faulty) output mean that the pointer was wrapping onto itself? any ideas on how it settled on the values 0, 1, 2 on the last three columns?

Comment: Since you wanted rows of 9 doubles (9*8 = 72 bytes), but ended up with rows of 9 ints (9*4 = 36 bytes), when you assigned 9 doubles, you ended up writing pass the index-ed row into the next rows memory. Then when that row assigned it's values, it overwrote the last values from the first row. This continues until the last row which doesn't get overwritten, but the memory it wrote into wasn't allocated and could end up getting used at some point by something else.

Comment: well thats something I completely overlooked, cheers for the incredibly quick response!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
double** makearray(int n2)
{
int i=0;
double** a;

a = malloc(n2 * sizeof(double *)); //<- was sizeof(int *)
if(a == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    exit(0);
    }

for(i = 0; i < n2; i++){
    a[i] = malloc(n2 * sizeof(double)); //<- was sizeof(int)
    if(a[i] == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit(0);
        }
    }

return a;

}
```